# The Concept Behind itertools's product Function

Tags: python, recursion, python-itertools

so basically i want to understand the concept of product() function in itertools. i mean what is the different between yield and return. And can this code be shorten down anyway.

```
    def product1(*args, **kwds):
        pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
        n = len(pools)
        if n == 0:
            yield ()
            return
        if any(len(pool) == 0 for pool in pools):
            return
        indices = [0] * n
        yield tuple(pool[i] for pool, i in zip(pools, indices))
        while 1:
            for i in reversed(range(n)):  # right to left
                if indices[i] == len(pools[i]) - 1:
                    continue
                indices[i] += 1
                for j in range(i+1, n):
                    indices[j] = 0
                yield tuple(pool[i] for pool, i in zip(pools, indices))
                break
            else:
                return
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Without `itertools` ? Then it's loops time I guess. is there a reason you wont use `itertools` ? or it's more like a challenge for urself ?

Comment: 1. Write the code using itertools. 2. Go to the itertools documentation. For each function you used, find the "this function is equivalent to the following code:" block. 3. Copy those blocks into your code.

Comment: If it is always `A` and `B` -- you could use `bin()` to get the binary expansion of all numbers in the range 0 to 2**n-1 and then replace `0` by `A` and `1` by `B` in the resulting strings.

Comment: @JohnColeman that would be easy and smooth. Nice one

Comment: I would highly recommend using the well established and tested `itertools` standard module. Reinventing the wheel is never advisable as a programmer.

That being said, we have no attempt at any code here, just a request for an answer (*sounds somewhat like homework*). I would start by taking a look at the `product()` function in itertools.

Comment: Your edit has radically changed the meaning of your question. Before the edit it was a reasonably focused albeit ad-hoc question. Now it is overly-broad. There is an awful lot going on in itertool's `product` function, too much to be explained in a Stack Overflow answer. If you have a focused *non-duplicate* question about `yield` vs. `return` then you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the work:

```
bytes = [i for i in range(2**(n))]
AB= []
for obj in bytes:
    t = str(bin(obj))[2:]
    t= '0'*(n-len(t)) + t
    AB.append(t.replace('0','A').replace('1','B'))
```

n being the string size wanted

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend using the well established and tested `itertools` [standard module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Reinventing the wheel is never *advisable* as a programmer. That said, I would start by taking a look at the `product()` function in itertools.

As for not using `itertools()`, this problem is essentially a **cartesian product** problem (*n-permutations with duplicates allowed*). This is where recursion helps us! One possible solution below:

**Method Body:**

```
result = []
def permutations(alphabet, repeat, total = ''):
    if repeat >= 1:
        for i in alphabet:
            # Add the subsolutions.     
            permutations(alphabet, repeat - 1, total + i)  

    else:
        result.append(total)
    return result
```

And when we call with `permutations()`

**Sample Outputs:**

```
permutations('ab', 3) ->
$ ['aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb']
permutations('ab', 3) ->
$ ['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'baa',
  'bab', 'bac', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab', 
  'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']
permutations('ab', 1) ->
$ ['a', 'b']
```

**How does it work?**

This method works by nesting for loops in a recursive manner *repeat*-times. We then accumulate the result of the sub-solutions, appending to a result list. So if we use **4** as our repeat value, out expanded *iterative* trace of this problem would look like the following:

```
for i in alphabet:
    for j in alphabet:
        for k in alphabet:
            for l in alphabet:
                result.append(i + j + k + l)
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman Added an answer! Hope you change your mind about the downvote :D

Comment: No problem -- although you could have just posted a new answer. Heck -- I'll even upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

First create a list with all the possible arrangements, that's easily achievable by summing binaries:

```
def generate_arrangements(n):
    return [bin(i)[2:].zfill(n) for i in range(2**n)]  # 2**n is number of possible options (A,B) n times
```

The [2:] slices the string and remove '0b' from it and zfill(n) completes the string with 0s until the string has length of n.

Now replace all 0,1 by A,B respectively:

```
arrangements = [arrangement.replace('0', 'A').replace('1', 'B') for arrangement in generate_arrangements(3)]
print(arrangements)
>> ['AAA', 'AAB', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'BBB']
```

If you want to put all together you have:

```
def generateAB(n):
    arrangements = [bin(i)[2:].zfill(n) for i in range(2**n)]
    return [arrangement.replace('0', 'A').replace('1', 'B') for arrangement in arrangements]
```